# CheckMarx scan on dot net application

Tags: checkmarx

Checkmarx scan complains that certain "element’s value flows through the code without being properly sanitized or validated and is eventually displayed to the user in method OnItemDataBound " in places where drop down values are passed or selected.Example:

```
strText = dropdownlist.SelectedValue;
```

or

```
return dropdownlist.SelectedValue;
```

How to sanitize these values?Can HTMLencode and decode apt to avoid such vulnerability results?

Note this is for an dot net application.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is referring to an XSS vulnerability finding, the resulting string is just like any other string, and is controllable by the attacker.
So yes, you should call HTMLEncode (or perform some other type of sanitization, deoending on context, e.g. AntiXSS) on that string before embedding in HTML - just like you would with any other external data.